# How can I sort a Meteor collection by time of insertion?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

I am working on my first project using Meteor, and am having some difficulty with sorting.

I have a form where users enter aphorisms that are then displayed in a list. Currently the most recent aphorisms automatically display at the bottom of the list. Is there an easy way to have the most recent appear at the top of the list instead?

I tried:

```
   Template.list.aphorisms = function () {
    return Aphorisms.find({}, {sort: {$natural:1}});
};
```

And am stumped because the Meteor docs don't have many examples.

Comment: You could always add a `date_created` attribute and sort by that.

Comment: How is your collection looks like?

Comment: I did add a date_created attribute...i was hoping with MongoDB that I wouldn't have to do that, though...

Comment: The default `_id` field is already keyed by creation time (see: how Mongo ObjectIDs are generated). You can just sort that in reverse order without having to add another field.

Comment: I am afraid Meteor uses own ObjectIDs without the timestamp part

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Assuming that the `date_created` is in a valid date format along with the timestamp, You should insert the parsed value of `date_created` using `Date.parse()` javascript function, which gives the number of milliseconds between January 1, 1970 and date value contained in `date_created`.

As a result of that, the most recently added record will contain greater value of  `date_created` than the record inserted before it.

Now when fetching the records, sort the cursor in descending order of the `date_created` parameter as:

```
 Aphorisms.find({}, {sort: {date_created: -1}});
```

This will sort records from newer to older.

Comment: This works very well..the only way I am currently only able to store the date in a way that works is: var combinedTime = year + "" + day + "" + month + "" + hour + "" + minute + "" + second;

Comment: Yeah, make sure `date_created` attribute contains a valid timestamp too. Since this will not work with only `date+month+year` .

Comment: In order to sort on dates client-side in minimongo, the date must be stored as a string, such as ISO8601 format. Minimongo does not know how to sort on Date types. See the text in red under http://docs.meteor.com/#collections

Comment: It changed a bit since '12: `date_created` is now `createdAt`

Answer (score 8):

I've found the following to be a cleaner solution:

```
   Template.list.aphorisms = function () {
      return Aphorisms.find().fetch().reverse();
   };
```

Given that entire collection already exists in the reverse order that you would like, you can simply create an array of all the objects and reverse the order.

Comment: I'm not sure you can actually rely on Mongo keeping your items in order. Theoretically, yes, this works — but to the best of my knowledge, this is not always a safe assumption.

Comment: This is the safest solution. MongoDB automatically creates a createdAt field by default in Meteor. So, when making large queries this is actually the safest and cleanest solution.

Comment: Hi, `createdAt` field is not created automatically (maybe it was at the time of your comment though, I use 1.4.2). You have to handle it by yourself, usually thanks to `aldeed:collection2` package.
I am not sure why this is not the default behaviour, as with mongoose or other languages.

Comment: You can not rely on the fact that the find will get the documents in creation order