# Sorting Name in mongodb using meteor

Tags: mongodb, sorting, meteor

I have a method as shown below on server.js file in meteor

```
  getNames : function(){
       var name = AccNames.find({}, {fields: {'Name': 1, '_id': 1}}).fetch();
        return name;
  }
```

How Can I sort the result in ascending order?
I mean how can I get the list of NAME in ascending order?
Is it possible to use fetch and sort together?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13957691/how-can-i-sort-a-meteor-collection-by-time-of-insertion.

Comment: How is it different? `AccNames.find({}, {fields: {'Name': 1, '_id': 1},{sort: {'Name': 1}}).fetch();` didn't work?

Comment: No its not working.i don't know whats wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use any one of the **[sort specifier](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/sortspecifiers)** syntaxes as another property in the **[`find()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find)** second argument object:

```
getNames: function(){
    // All of these do the same thing (sort in ascending order by key "name"

    /* 
       var sort_fields = [["Name", "asc"]];
       also the same as var sort_fields = ["Name"];
    */
    var sort_fields = {'Name': 1};
    var projection = {'Name': 1, '_id': 1};
    return AccNames.find({}, {fields: projection, sort: sort_fields}).fetch();    
}
```

Comment: Prefect Thanks a lot!